# storing value return by function in variable of if statement and use in other condition -php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, if-statement

I have a function `wp_get_category($id)` that return true, false or return an array object with error description. I want to check if function return false or object then return error object or other error for false,

```
if( strlen($id) > 64)
    {
        return array('return' => array( 'responseData' => array( 'error' => 'Invalid ID.'), 'Code' => 400 ));
    }
    else if( !$my_array=wp_get_category($id) || is_object($my_array))
    {
        if(is_object($my_array))
        {
            return $my_array;
        }
        return array('return' => array( 'responseData' => array( 'error' => 'Invalid ID.'), 'Code' => 404 ));
    }
```

Is it possible with php to use `$my_array` in other condition ?
I don't want to call function again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple make it global and then use in another functions.

Add to the beginning of this function (I assume this is function because you use `return`)

```
global $my_array;
```

and in other functions you want to use this variable also paste:

```
global $my_array;
```

PS. I know that using `global` is not the best practice however it's wordpress and I don't know how can it be done using other methods